# About principled bsdf parameter "Subsurface" in node_principled_bsdf.osl

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, blender-internal-render-engine, source-code, subsurface-scattering

According to Blender manual, Subsurface

> Mix between diffuse and subsurface scattering

> it acts as a multiplier for the Subsurface Radius.

After checking the source code, I found:

`vector radius = max(SubsurfaceScale * SubsurfaceRadius, vector(0.0));`

`BSDF = mix(BSDF, clamped_base_color * SubsurfBSDF, subsurface_weight);`

So, the question is what parameter of *Principled BSDF Subsurface* is? SubsurfaceScale or subsurface_weight? because depend on blender manual description, it seems like both?what realitionship of three of them，I'm so confused

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]